# Stereo selective reaction products

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality, organic-reduction, stereoselectivity

> Pyruvic acid on reduction with yeast gives **(-)** lactic acid while with $\ce{NaBH4}$ it reduces to **(+)** lactic acid. How?

I know this has something to do with stereoselectivity. But I don't know which one would be a correct answer.

It would be more helpful if you could explain a bit about stereo-selective reactions. I know what it is, what I want to know is, how to find which of the products will be stereochemically preferred one, just like in this question.

Comment: There is no way that borohydride reduction of pyruvic acid can give anything other than racemic lactic acid.

Answer (score 3):

Enyzmatic reduction (as would occur in yeast) could easily be a stereoselective process - probably via selective delivery of a hydride from NADH.

As the other respondent notes, there is simply no way that combining achiral reagents (pyruvic acid and NaBH4) can yield anything other than a racemic product.

Comment: That is the exact reason, I'm asking this question for.I have read it in  O P Tondon's  organic chemistry for competitions book.

Comment: As for the answer, how may I know or predict ,the product formed after stereoselectivy. Is there a way to predict what should be the major product or something?